# fill text method is not changing the given text for each context in canvas

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I tried to change the text on each canvas by using the `ctx.fillText` method, but all the canvas are displaying the last text given to the canvas.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas-' + i).getContext('2d');
image = new Image();
candidatePerformance = $('#performance'+i).val(); 
skillSet = $('#skillSet'+i).val(); 
verificationId = $('#verificationId'+i).val();
(function(ctx, image) {
    image.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        ctx.font = '15pt Arial '; ctx.fillStyle = "#fff"; ctx.textAlign = 'left'; ctx.fillText(skillSet,10,125);
        ctx.font = '15pt Arial'; ctx.fillStyle = "#fff"; ctx.textAlign = 'left'; ctx.fillText(performance,160,155);
        ctx.font = '15pt Arial'; ctx.fillStyle = "#fff"; ctx.textAlign = 'left'; ctx.fillText(verificationId,49,185);
    };
    image.src = $('#img'+i).val();
})(ctx, image);
```

Comment: Can you please provide more code, you have the variable `i` but I can't see it declared, It looks like it is in an each loop but I can't assume that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/z7xa757w/

```
image = new Image();
image.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/Large_Siamese_cat_tosses_a_mouse.jpg";

image.onload = function () {
    for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas-' + i).getContext('2d');

        var candidatePerformance = $('#performance' + i).val();
        var skillSet = $('#skillSet' + i).val();
        var verificationId = $('#verificationId' + i).val();

            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
            ctx.font = '15pt Arial ';
            ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
            ctx.textAlign = 'left';
            ctx.fillText(skillSet, 10, 125);
            ctx.font = '15pt Arial';
            ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
            ctx.textAlign = 'left';
            ctx.fillText(performance, 160, 155);
            ctx.font = '15pt Arial';
            ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
            ctx.textAlign = 'left';
            ctx.fillText(verificationId, 49, 185);

    }
}
```